# Ansible showing different version for root and non-root users

Tags: apt, root, ansible

I need to use an older version of Ansible (2.9). I added the repo using `add-apt-repository ppa:ansible/ansible-2.9`. When I run `ansible --version` as root, I get:

```
ansible 2.9.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) [GCC 9.3.0]
```

However, when I run the same command as my normal user, I get:

```
ansible 2.10.3
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/christopher/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/christopher/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) [GCC 9.3.0]
```

I have **no** idea what is going on. I can't even use Ansible right now because every playbook crashes due to it not recognizing modules such as `package`. Where do I find this 2.10.3 version and get rid of it!?

Comment: See `pip list`. It seems you've installed Ansible both via *pip* and a *system package manager*.

Comment: Ran "pip3 list" and found `ansible-base-2.10.3` (which is the version I do not want).

Comment: `pip3 uninstall ansible-base` worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip3 list`

Found `ansible-base 2.10.3`

`pip3 uninstall ansible-base`

Ran `ansible --version` on both myself and sudo. Both are 2.9.6 now

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.9.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) [GCC 9.3.0]
```

**as root**

```
ansible --version    
ansible 2.9.6
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.8.5 (default, Jul 28 2020, 12:59:40) [GCC 9.3.0]
```